# ppa/git problems after installing certificates. Revert system to default?

Tags: ppa

I have installed some certificates and after I did it i have a lot of problems with the ppa and git:

1. `sudo apt update` returns errors for missing release files where they actually are:

   ```
   server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
   E: The repository 'https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable stable Release' does not have a Release file.
   N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
   ```

But if you follow the link above you will see that there is a Release file.

2. adding a repository via terminal results in this message, no matter what user/ppa I try to add:

   ```
   Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~teejee2008/ubuntu/ppa'.
   ERROR: '~teejee2008' user or team does not exist.
   ```
3. `git pull origin master`

   ```
   fatal: unable to access 'https://path-to-repository.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
   ```

A workaround here is to set `export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1`, but it is not a nice solution.

Because the certificates I have already installed are not necessary anymore, is it possible to revert the certificate system to default without reinstalling the elementary OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes after installing some certificates, and did not resolve when I removed them, not even using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates` or `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`.

The solution I found was to completely remove the `ca-certificates` package and install it again, instead of using `--reinstall`.

```
sudo apt remove --purge ca-certificates
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install ca-certificates
```

and because the `autoremove` removed `software-properties-common`, I have to install it again by typing

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

After these steps I can add repositories, use `git pull` and `sudo apt update` without any problems.