# ElementaryOS broken packages

Tags: release-loki, updates, ppa

I am having a trouble whenever I want to install a new package or run `sudo apt-get update` with the following message:

```
W: The repository 'http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.28.5.44 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here is a screenshot of my software packages

[image: packages list]
So, how can I fix this problem and get the broken messages repaired?

Comment: I don't know. I think it was a server related problem "certificate, blocking, proxy ... " it was fixed itself :) thanks @Ravan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, I did a research and found 2 possible reasons - 
mis-configured proxy and certificates problem. In my case the reason was certificates mess, my resolution you can see [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/14254/ppa-git-problems-after-installing-certificates-revert-system-to-default)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was fixed without doing anything. But yeah, it's a certificate problem.